# Is it necessay to pass 0 to an array

Tags: c, arrays

If i don't pass zero to the array this works absolutely fine why so? When does it really count to add pass zero or specify array has is empty? Please give me an example.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=  34;
    char array[10]={0};

    itoa(i, array, 10);

    printf("%s\n", array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually your are initializing the array at declaring time. If you not this will rise exception. Else it will print some garbage data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
char array[10];
```

You tell the computer to allocate a 10 `char` long memory location to you, assign the address of the first location to the variable called `array`.

When you write:

```
char array[10] = { 1 };
```

Additionally, you tell the computer set the first memory location to have the value `1` (because you have written `1` there), and the rest are to be set to `0` (this happens for every non-specified remaining locations, and is `0` regardless of what the specified ones were).

When you do like:

```
char array[10] = { 0 };
```

You just set all 10 with `0`s.

If you do not need each location, each element of the array to start with a `0`, then it is all fine to not initialize them. Following code is all good:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( ) {
    char array[10];

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        array[i] = i + 1;   // sets them from 1 to 10

    printf( "%d", array[5] );   // prints 6

    return 0;
}
```

But this one will display a not-necessarily-consistent value:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( ) {
    char array[10];

    printf( "%d", array[5] );   // may print anything

    return 0;
}
```

For example, it displayed `-52` on my end. It could very well display anything between `-128` and `127`.

Answer (score 2):

Here, you don't need to initialize the array to zero. `itoa` doesn't require that the buffer it's using is initialized. It'll just write over anything you initialize the array to, anyway.

If you were doing something that actually needed the array to start out full of zeros, the `= {0}` would be necessary. If you don't initialize the array, accessing its values is undefined behavior:

```
int array[10];
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Probably adds up garbage; might do anything.
    x += array[i];
}
printf("%d\n", x); // Probably prints garbage; might do anything.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't initialise variable, it contains garbage. In this given example you don't care about it - because you never reading it *before* overwriting array contents with `itoa`.

If you'll read variable before initialising or assigning any value to it - you never know what exactly will come as result.